# How to calculate witness pair for Big O?

Tags: math, big-o, logarithm

Can someone explain how to use witness pairs in the case where you have to show that log n^2 is O(log n) ? Please give an example of how you came up with any particular witness pair.

Comment: The term "witness pair" isn't very standard.  The OP is looking for the concrete choices of n0 and c used in the formal definition of big-O notation.

Answer (score 0):

By the Power Rule for logarithms, we have

> log (n<sup>2</sup>) = 2 log n

Therefore, we have for any choice of n that log (n<sup>2</sup>) = 2 log n.  Therefore, if we pick n<sub>0</sub> = 1 and c = 2, we have that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> that log (n<sup>2</sup>) ≤ c log n.

Hope this helps!